# parameterized Cypher query not working in Neography

Tags: neo4j, neography

Trying to execute a parameterized Cypher query with Neography v0.0.23.

Even though the non-parameterized version works:

```
Neo.execute_query("start n=node(3) return n")
 => {"data"=>[[{....
```

The parameterized version doesnt work:

```
Neo.execute_query("start n=node(id) return n", {:id => 3})
 => nil
```

Comment: upgraded to Neography 0.0.25 and the issue persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "start n=node({id}) return n" with the parameter name in curly brackets.